# Open Street Map Marker Manager

Tags: javascript, google-maps, openstreetmap

I need kind of Marker Manager for OpenStreetMap like in google maps.
Do somebody know anything about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend looking at using the Google API with OpenStreetMap (or equivalent) map tiles. http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Google_Maps_Example is an example of using the OSM tiles in the Google Maps API, where you will be able to use the Google Marker Manager.

Answer (score 1):

OpenStreetMap is only the map data. To view the map, the most common thing (and the thing shown on the OpenStreetMap home page) is the Javascript library [Openlayers](http://openlayers.org/). This gives capabilities similar to the Google Javascript APIs - you can add markers, load KML overlays etc.

Please be a bit more specific about what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm talking about realization http://gmaps-utility-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markermanager/release/docs/reference.html Marker Manager for openlayers.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen, there are no markers, only POIs, which you can upload in the form of an [OSM file](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/POI-Upload). Perhaps you can [add this functionality yourself](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Develop) - OSM is an open source project.